# How to test a DLT pipeline inorder to achieve TDD approch

Tags: tdd, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

As per this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/product/2021/may#create-and-manage-etl-pipelines-using-delta-live-tables-public-preview DLT enables the test driven development approach for creating and managing the etl pipeline. Is there any reference notebook or documentation link which helps and guide on how can we do the testing on this.

Comment: what language do you use to program DLT?